# Not able to pass the method as POST from django template to django view

Tags: django, django-forms

I am making a Django form but not able to pass the form as a "POST" method. When I press the submit button, the form information is sent as "GET" which I can see by printing on the terminal. Hence the if condition in the code remains false. Please help me figure out what is going wrong here.

Below is the code for the rendering the template.

```
# Code for the /template.py#

  {% block content %}
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h1>Please answer the question</h1>
        <form method="post">
             {% crispy user_form user_form.helper %}
            <p><input type="submit" class='btn btn-primary' value="Submit" 
            method = "post"></p>
            {% csrf_token %}  
        </form>
     </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  {% endblock %}
```

Below is the code in the views.py file.

```
# /*Code for the /views.py*/
def launch_survey(request, pagelink):
    pagelink_html = pagelink+".html"
    user_form = FormQuestionaire()
    print(request.method)
    if (request.method == 'post'):
        print("We are not here")
        user_form = FormQuestionaire(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid():
            print('Validation Success')
            print("NAME: "+user_form.cleaned_data['First_name'])

return render(request, "modern_business/"+pagelink_html, {'user_form':user_form})
```

Below is the code in the forms.py file.

```
# /*FORMS.PY*/

from django import forms
from firstapp.models import Questionaire
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from django.core import validators

class FormQuestionaire(forms.ModelForm):
    helper = FormHelper()
    helper.form_show_labels = True
    helper.form_class = 'form-group row'
    helper._form_method = "post"

    CHOICES = [('1', 'First'), ('2', 'Second')]

    choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, 
                   widget=forms.RadioSelect,
                   label = "Do you like this website?", initial = '1',
                   required = True,)
    mult_field 
    = forms.ChoiceField
     (widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
      choices=CHOICES,
      label = "Do you like our Checkbox?", required = True,)

    class Meta:
        model = Questionaire
        fields = ['First_name', 'Last_name', 'email', 'paid']
        labels  = {'First_name': ('Enter Your first name') ,
                   'Last_name': ('Enter your last name'),
                   'Enter your email': ('Whether it is paid'),}

print(request.method) always prints GET even though form is set to POST.
```

Comment: I'm confused. You are printing the request.method within forms.py and not views.py. Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: print(request.method) always prints GET even though form is set to POST.  - is just a comment to describe my problem.   The same is printed in the views. py file as below                                                                                                
    def launch_survey(request, pagelink):
    pagelink_html = pagelink+".html"
    user_form = FormQuestionaire()
    print(request.method)

Comment: Not tried a debugger..

Answer (score 0):

The method is always in all caps.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
```

Comment: I changed all "post" to "POST" but it does not change anything. The template still sends the form as GET to the Views.